# Thymeleaf 3 map access with dot notation

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

While updating thymeleaf from 2.x to 3.x in a spring 4.3.x environment, I am facing the problem that the class *org.thymeleaf.context.VariablesMap* was removed. 
I am using the following model structure

```
public interface Model extends Map<String, Object>, Serializable {...}
public class BaseModel extends VariablesMap<String, Object> implements Model {...}
```

VariablesMap implemented an OGNL MapPropertyAccessor which allowed to access the model with the dot notation, regardless of whether the key *alternativeLanguages* exists or not

```
${meta.alternativeLanguages}
```

Now with thymeleaf 3 the spring integration only uses SpringEL and the SpringEL MapAccessor throws an exception when the key *alternativeLanguages* does not exists

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 28): Property or field 'alternativeLanguages' cannot be found on object of type 'd.v.BaseModel' - maybe not public?
```

Is there a way to avoid the migration of all templates to

```
${meta['alternativeLanguages']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial answer as I haven't tried it, but I'm guessing you'll have to implement your own `org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor` based on (possibly inheriting from) the `org.springframework.context.expression.MapAccessor` that isn't quite doing what you want. You'd want to pretty much always return true for the `canRead` method, and handle the `read` method to return whatever it is you want it to return in the case that the map doesn't have the value in it.

Then I assume you'd need to somehow hook into how Thymeleaf creates its SpEL context to register that custom `PropertyAccessor`, which I would expect to be possible but I didn't see where in a quick look through.

I hope that gets you pointed in the right direction, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I found out the last days. But sadly the implementation of org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView, where the SpEL context is registered, is not open to extension. Especially the renderFragment() method is a mess.

Answer (score -2):

You could use safe null navigation in this case:
`${meta?.alternativeLanguages}`
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly the Exception is thrown before the expression is evaluated.

Comment: The safe null navigation operator would only help if the problem was that the `meta` value is null, which isn't the case here.